# Where could I find a full list of functions for MT4, for a direct socket communications?

Tags: c#, metatrader4

I've read other posts about using **`USERHISTORY`** and **`QUOTES`** messages / functions in order to receive information trough an MetaTrader 4 account, without using the MetaTrader 4 Terminal, but I don't know where to find the full list of functions that could be used with this method. Please help

Answer (score 0):

### I. Legal aspect:

MetaQuotes, Inc., will not like anybody to go this way. About a decade back, there were a season of trying to bypass a MetaTrader Terminal piece of software and there were a few successful implementations of Web-based trading GUI, that was able to use the wire-( you call it a socket )-protocol and fully perform the user experience of having trading GUI - trading Server side interactions right without the MetaTrader Terminal part.

Next came lawsuits, for violation of the protected rights for any intellectual property or whatever other reason and none of the Terminal-less trading innovators remained in business.

Definitely not a way to go, if you plan to do a business in this domain.

---

### II. Technical part:

Given the above, do not expect to have any documented basis available for you to get your reverse-engineering efforts a single step easier. Next, get also ready, that the simplest thing a software may use to fight against any such motivated reverse-engineering is a frequent update of the socket-level handshaking and data exchange ( which was observed several times ), not mentioning the always present chance to start using a polymorphic obfuscation engine for further raise the yardstick for the reverse-engineering efforts.

---

### III. If indeed a keen hobbyist, having this still on one's Bucket List:

For this endeavour, there exists a legally gray zone ( respecting the Chapter I. above ), where you setup your in-vivo System-under-Test and operate all the possible interactions on MetaTrader Terminal, as all the rest of the world does, and have some tools, like a wire-attached analyser / packet sniffer, that will help you decode the MT4-Terminal **`<-->`** MT4-Server "wire-level" protocol handshaking and data exchange.

This way, one can "build"-by-example the required "full list" that technically could be used ( sure, with having all the complete Terminal-side context fully emulated first ) in-vivo.